# How to disable hjkl movements?

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-layout

Before you crucify me please note I have a an Ultimate Hacking Keyboard and I already can move with arrow keys on the home row :)

I suppose I don't have to since I have a different layer to activate my arrow keys on the home row but still.

Comment: Just because a key exists on your keyboard doesn't mean that you have to use it. If you don't wat to use `hjkl` for navigation… just don't.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 6):

I would do:

```
nnoremap h <Nop>
nnoremap j <Nop>
nnoremap k <Nop>
nnoremap l <Nop>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vim-hardtime](https://github.com/takac/vim-hardtime) to help fix bad habits with regard to hitting `hjkl`. It will only allow you to press these keys once per second (sometime you only need to shift one letter/line)

Comment: My reading of the OP is different and somehow opposite. He want not to use the functionality instead of being forces to use the right move.

Comment: @vivian you are correct, but I do appreciate the intent to help from Jonathan thank you both :)

Comment: The important for me is that you have solution :-) Vote for the ones that are helpful and accept one of them using the v button if you have a solution such that the question can rest :-)